# Better to have decrementing loops?

Tags: c#, c, vhdl

I remember years ago hearing that it is more efficient to have loops decrementing instead of incrementing especially when programming microprocessors.
Is this true, and if so, what are the reasons?

Comment: Maybe it depends on the assembler directive `LOOP` that decrements `ECX` to zero. But on high level languages this should not make much of an effect.

Comment: The C# tag is confusing: your question depends on the cpu architecture, but C# is compiled into IL code that can be translated into different machine code instructions depending on the instruction set

Comment: If you have actual code that is faster one way than the other, post it and ask why. Otherwise, this isn't a terribly useful question.

Comment: Mystified as to the close reason on this one.

Comment: good question, voting to reopen. Tagged very poorly though.

Comment: @gabe there's more to computing than trial and error

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One thing that occurs off the bat is that the end condition on a decrementing loop is liable to be quicker. If you are looping up to a certian value, a comparison with that value is going to be required every iteration. However, if you are looping down to zero, then the decrement itself on most processors will set the zero flag if the value being decremented hits zero, so no extra comparison operation will be required.

Small potatoes I realize, but in a large tight inner loop it might matter a great deal.

Comment: If you can post some timing analysis showing this effect, this question might be worth reopening.

Comment: @Gabe - An odd request. In general, I actually applaud your suspicion of micro-optimizing like this. I'm certianly not obfuscating HLL code of mine to do this unless I have numbers showing it helps a great deal. However, the fact that (on processors like the M68K or Ix86's) this requires an extra instruction is beyond doubt. I don't think I really have the free time required to conclusively prove to you that executing no instruction is faster than executing an instruction.

Comment: I found this http://www.c-jump.com/CIS77/reference/ISA/DDU0103.html which indicates that a comparison DOES take place (CMP CX,0). Also, doesn't setting a flag require the code to compare the value of the flag?

Comment: @lejon I think you may be misreading what that link is saying. For your "also", a typical branching instruction in a loop is something like [`BNE dest`](https://www.c64-wiki.com/index.php/BNE) (if the zero flag isn't set, branch to "dest"). These instructions are implemented by hardware, and are typically quite fast, like a cycle or two. Of course on a pipelined architecture you have to factor in branch prediction failures...

Answer (score 2):

In c# it makes no difference to the efficiency.  The only reason to have decrementing loops is if you are looping through a collection and removing items as you go.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about decrementing, but I know that using ++i instead of i++ is more performant.

There are lots of articles on the web why this is, but it comes down to this: using ++i makes it so that i gets declared the first time automaticly, and using i++ doesn't do that. (in C# at least)

Again, don't know if decrementing is more performant, just thought I'd throw that out there seeing how you're asking about performance :)

You'd just use decrementing because it's easier in some situations for all I know..